Zoom integration with Android app, library "libc++_shared.so" not found
I am using zoom sdk in Android.
When I tried to run their a project in the SDK package ->
(mobilertc-android project in Android Studio).
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: us.zoom.sdkexample, PID: 9094
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc++\_shared.so" not found
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1081)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1003)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1765)
at com.zipow.cmmlib.AppContext.\<clinit\>(:1)
at us.zoom.internal.impl.i0.a(:63)
at us.zoom.sdk.ZoomSDK.initialize(:1)

The same thing happened multiple times when I tried with other methods.
**Troubleshooting: conflicts with libc++_shared.so
To fix a conflict with libc++_shared.so, try these options in this order. Check after each change to see if that fix resolves the issue.
Check the project's NDK version. Our SDK's current supported NDK version is r25c. If you’re not sure which version you're using, define the NDK version in the build.gradle file.
Check if there’s any other libc++_shared.so in your project that causes a conflict.
If you have your own C++ library in your project, define the ndkVersion 23 in build.gradle.
If you're using a third-party module that includes libc++_shared.so, remove the third-party module from your project or remove libc++_share.so from the module.**
I tried the solutions recommended on https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/android/integrate/ but it doesn't help.
I changed the NDK version, added the package and don't think there's duplicate "libc++_shared.so". Or maybe I'm missing something.
Please let me know if you've been to same situation and how you solved it. Much appreciated.
